# Swift Custom UIAlertView

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller, completionhandler

I'm trying to make a confirm deletion popup view. Because the design I want is very different from the style of the typical `UIAlertView` popup, I decided to create a custom `ConfirmationViewController` that I would trigger to popup.

Here is what the typical `UIAlertView` looks like:

[image]

And here's what I want mine to look like:

[image]

Here's how I'm currently making my custom `ConfirmationViewController` popup:

```
let confirmationViewController = ConfirmationViewController()
confirmationViewController.delegate = self
confirmationViewController.setTitleLabel("Are you sure you want to remove \(firstName)?")
confirmationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
confirmationViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(230, 130)

let popoverConfirmationViewController = confirmationViewController.popoverPresentationController
popoverConfirmationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
popoverConfirmationViewController?.delegate = self
popoverConfirmationViewController?.sourceView = self.view
popoverConfirmationViewController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds),0,0)
presentViewController(
    confirmationViewController,
    animated: true,
    completion: nil)
```

And here's how I'm getting the notification when the `CANCEL` or `REMOVE` button is pressed:

```
extension UserProfileTableViewController: ConfirmationViewControllerDelegate {
    func cancelButtonPressed() {
        print("Cancel button pressed")
    }

    func confirmationButtonPressed(objectToDelete: AnyObject?) {
        print("Delete button pressed")
    }
}
```

However, what I like about using a `UIAlertView` is that I can hardcode in the action I want performed when a particular button is pressed, like this:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: {(ACTION) in
    print("Perform cancel action")
})

let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Remove", style: .Destructive, handler: {(ACTION) in
    print("Perform delete action")
})

alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
alertController.addAction(deleteAction)

presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So my question is, how can I create a completion handler (inline) in such a way that when the `CANCEL` or `REMOVE` button is pressed with my custom `ConfirmationViewController` I can trigger the action, just as I've shown how it's done with the `UIAlertController`, instead of the current way I'm doing it with delegation?

Is the answer to just create the custom popup I'm looking for with a `UIAlertController`? And if so, how can I customize it to the degree I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post :)

P.S. Here's what my `ConfirmationViewController` and `ConfirmationViewControllerDelegate` look like:

```
protocol ConfirmationViewControllerDelegate {
    func cancelButtonPressed()
    func confirmationButtonPressed(objectToDelete: AnyObject?)
}

class ConfirmationViewController: UIViewController {
    var didSetupConstraints = false

    let titleLabel = UILabel.newAutoLayoutView()
    let buttonContainer = UIView.newAutoLayoutView()
    let cancelButton = ButtonWithPressingEffect.newAutoLayoutView()
    let confirmationButton = ButtonWithPressingEffect.newAutoLayoutView()

    var delegate: ConfirmationViewControllerDelegate?

    var objectToDelete: AnyObject?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorFromCode(0x7f7f7f)
        cancelButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cancelButton.setAttributedTitle(NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: "CANCEL",
            attributes: [
                NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextLTPro-Demi", size: 12)!,
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
                NSKernAttributeName: 0.2
            ]
        ), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        confirmationButton.backgroundColor = Application.redColor
        confirmationButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        confirmationButton.setAttributedTitle(NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: "REMOVE",
            attributes: [
                NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextLTPro-Demi", size: 12)!,
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
                NSKernAttributeName: 0.2
            ]
        ), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        confirmationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(confirmationButtonPresssed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(titleLabel)
        view.addSubview(buttonContainer)
        buttonContainer.addSubview(cancelButton)
        buttonContainer.addSubview(confirmationButton)
        updateViewConstraints()
    }

    func cancelButtonPressed() {
        delegate?.cancelButtonPressed()
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }

    func confirmationButtonPresssed() {
        delegate?.confirmationButtonPressed(objectToDelete)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }

    func setTitleLabel(text: String) {
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 4.5
        titleLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: text,
            attributes: [
                NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextLTPro-Regular", size: 14)!,
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.colorFromCode(0x151515),
                NSKernAttributeName: 0.5,
                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
            ]
        )
    }

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        if !didSetupConstraints {
            titleLabel.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10), excludingEdge: .Bottom)
            titleLabel.autoAlignAxisToSuperviewAxis(.Vertical)

            buttonContainer.autoPinEdge(.Top, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: titleLabel, withOffset: 3)
            buttonContainer.autoAlignAxisToSuperviewAxis(.Vertical)
            buttonContainer.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Bottom, withInset: 10)

            let contactViews: NSArray = [cancelButton, confirmationButton]
            contactViews.autoDistributeViewsAlongAxis(.Horizontal, alignedTo: .Horizontal, withFixedSpacing: 7, insetSpacing: true, matchedSizes: false)

            cancelButton.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Top)
            cancelButton.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Bottom)
            cancelButton.autoSetDimensionsToSize(CGSize(width: 100, height: 50))

            confirmationButton.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Top)
            confirmationButton.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Bottom)
            confirmationButton.autoSetDimensionsToSize(CGSize(width: 100, height: 50))

            didSetupConstraints = true
        }

        super.updateViewConstraints()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the ConfirmationViewController class under your control and possible to edit?

Comment: Yessir, I just updated to include my code for the ConfirmationViewController @SeanCAtkinson

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like the following should allow it. Note there quite a few improvements that could be made. For example you could use a generic for the object being deleted instead of AnyObject. You also don't necessarily need to pass it in if you pass the closure inline anyway so you could probably just remove it.

You could also make your buttons more reusable rather than hard-coding to cancel and remove but now we're getting off topic :)

```
class ConfirmViewController : UIViewController {
    var onCancel : (() -> Void)?
    var onConfirm : ((AnyObject?) -> Void)?

    var objectToDelete : AnyObject?

    func cancelButtonPressed() {
        // defered to ensure it is performed no matter what code path is taken
        defer {
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        }

        let onCancel = self.onCancel
        // deliberately set to nil just in case there is a self reference
        self.onCancel = nil
        guard let block = onCancel else { return }
        block()
    }

    func confirmationButtonPresssed() {
        // defered to ensure it is performed no matter what code path is taken
        defer {
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        }
        let onConfirm = self.onConfirm
        // deliberately set to nil just in case there is a self reference
        self.onConfirm = nil
        guard let block = onConfirm else { return }
        block(self.objectToDelete)
    }
}

let confirm = ConfirmViewController()
confirm.objectToDelete = NSObject()
confirm.onCancel = {
    // perform some action here
}
confirm.onConfirm = { objectToDelete in
    // delete your object here
}
```

Comment: I like this design pattern a lot. Is there a particular reason one would use delegation over this kind of pattern for views? @SeanCAtkinson

Comment: Depends on the use case really. In this case, a block based API works nicely because it is simple and you can declare the behaviour when you create the instance. As your needs get more complex, you'll trend towards a delegate instead.

Comment: Quick question.. what if I want to make it so that the onConfirm function references a variable that will be modified in the ConfirmationViewController? Whatever objects I use in the onConfirm function will be set for whatever the object's value was at the time I passed it in, not when the code is actually run, correct?

Comment: I would need to use delegation for this case, correct? @SeanCAtkinson

Comment: It will hold the variable in the ConfirmationViewController by reference, not the value itself. That means that if the value has changed by the time the onComfirm block runs, it will use the new value rather than the old value. If you need it to use the old value instead, capture the particular value you want in a local variable outside of where you declare the onConfirm block and reference that new variable instead.